# how to apply jenkins parameter plugin to existing jobs

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to be able to select among the existing JDKs in the job configuration which is provided by the [jdk parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/jenkins/jdk+parameter+plugin). Newly created jobs offer that selection, but I need it on a whole bunch of existing jobs, where the drop down menu doesn't show up. All of my software (jenkins + plugin) is recent (2.72)

Comment: I did not get this issue when I install new plugin but did you work around like `restart jenkins service` or `clone/copy current job to new job`? If its still not effect, I think new plugin does not support current job type.

Comment: if you run each job once without any parameters, does it sort itself out? i think this is a known issue / limitation.